# Perl print changes order of execution

Tags: perl, printing, ssh

I got a pretty strange problem with my perl-script. I really have no idea, what's happening there, maybe you will see it...

My script uses `Net::SSH::Perl` to connect to a host-machine via SSH. After that I `head -20` on a config.ini and search for some pattern (a version number).

After I print the version number i `cat` some other file which is approximately 700 lines long.

What's happening now is, that instead of printing the version-number, the script prints the whole 700-line-file. **Unless I add**`print "\n"x10;` **directly behind the version-print**.

This behaviour doesn't make any sense to me, but I'm sure one of you will be smarter than me and know the answer :)

Below the script:

```
  1 #!/usr/local/bin/perl -w
  2 use lib './';
  3 use strict;
  4
  5 use GetVersions;
  6 use Net::SSH::Perl;
  7
  8
  9 my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new(
 10         'host',
 11         identity_files => ['~/.ssh/id_rsa']
 12 );
 13
 14 $ssh->login('user');
 15
 16 my $ver_regex = '^psadm\.version\s*=\s*rel_(.+)$';
 17
 18 my ($file, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('head -20 /config.ini');
 19 my $version = $file =~ /$ver_regex/m;
 20 print "version: $version\n",
 21 #print "\n"x10;
 22 ($file, $err, $exit) = $ssh->cmd('cat /application.ini');
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should probably be a semicolon

```
print "version: $version\n",
                           ^
```

Comment: +1 nice catch. Its funny that the extra `print` statement actually just adds a semi-colon to fix the problem, and could be any statement. It should also add a `1` to the end of the version number, since it will print the return value of `print`.

Comment: It would have the added weirdness of printing the file content before the version number (see `print 2, print 3`).

Comment: Oh, thank you so much :-D I was staring at this code with another coworker for literally hours and we just didn't see that. You sir, are awesome!